# IndexError: list index out of range error in sys argv

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm trying to upload a file to google cloud using the below Python code and it throws the list index out of range error. Can someone help me resolve this issue please ?

```
import sys
from sys import argv


from google.cloud import storage


def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    bucket_name = "test1"
    # The path to your file to upload
    source_file_name = "C:/Users/test/p3.csv"
    # The ID of your GCS object
    destination_blob_name = "Test_Upload"
    kms_key_name ="C:/Users/test/df08d120148c00.json"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name,kms_key_name=kms_key_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print(
        f"File {source_file_name} uploaded to {destination_blob_name}."
    )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    upload_blob(
        bucket_name=sys.argv[1],
        source_file_name=sys.argv[2],
        destination_blob_name=sys.argv[3],
    )
```

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace/Traceback

Comment: Does printing `sys.argv`  show all three arguments?

Comment: @darthbaba 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test\vscodeadmanager\.venv\UploadFile_GCS.py", line 36, in <module>
    bucket_name=sys.argv[1],
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Lakshmi_N looks like you're not passing the required number of arguments.
eg: `python3 filename.py arg1 arg2 arg3`

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine  
No , its not printing those 3 arguments.
`Arg list :  ['c:/Users/test/vscodeadmanager/.venv/UploadFile_GCS.py']` . This is what it prints when I tried ` print ("Arg list : ",str(sys.argv))`

Comment: Your script expects you to pass 3 arguments [sys.argv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/)

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine Thank you !! It worked .
I have been running the code in VSCode . But then I tried executing the script ` python UploadFile_GCS.py test1 C:/Users/test/p3.csv Test_Upload`